# How to set random value in the specified range in variable?

Tags: nginx

How to set random value in the specified range in variable *without 3rd party modules* in nginx's config?

Something like

```
set    $random_value         rand(1,4);
```

Comment: What is your final goal?

Comment: @quanta: Final goal is   
`fastcgi_cache_key "$request_method|$host|$request_uri|$random_value";`

Answer (score 1):

using macports:

afte reading those
https://trac.macports.org/ticket/19342
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812596/installing-nginx-via-macports-with-ngx-echo-module-available

(has to be perl 5.8 or 5.10)

```
# port -f install perl5 +perl5_8
# port clean nginx
# port install nginx +perl5
```

I cant post more links, find the /HttpEchoModule#Installation on the nginx site

```
cd /opt/local/src/
```

download the tgz here: https://github.com/agentzh/echo-nginx-module/downloads
tar -zxvf /Users/lorieri/Downloads/agentzh-echo-nginx-module-v0.37rc7-1-gb0e0a23.tar.gz

```
port edit nginx
```

add those lines, between any other variant

```
variant echo description {Add echo } {
    configure.args-append --add-module=/opt/local/src/agentzh-echo-nginx-module-b0e0a23
}
```

then...

```
# port install -v nginx +perl5 +echo
```

edit /opt/local/etc/nginx and mention in the previous (below) comment, in the http context
then edit same file to add test location

```
    location /lorieri {
            default_type text/plain;
            echo $rnd;
    }
```

run nginx

```
# nginx
```

test it with curl, wget, your browser...

```
# curl localhost/lorieri
9
# curl localhost/lorieri
8
# curl localhost/lorieri
8
# curl localhost/lorieri
9
# curl localhost/lorieri
6
```

why I did that ? to set on nginx a cookie user_uid for a year and a random cookie for the current session

Answer (score 0):

```
        http {
             perl_set  $rnd 'sub { return int(rand(10 - 5)) + 5; }';
             ...
        }
```

Using perl module.

And what is the goal of such caching?

Comment: `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "perl_set"`

Comment: I want to do this without 3rd party modules. 
Goal of such caching is dynamic random content.

Comment: perl_module is standard but optional. Use --with-http_perl_module.

Comment: It seems to me that you can store pages on disk by using backend script and then use random_index module: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRandomIndexModule